# Debug.WriteLine to different "channel"?

Tags: c#, debugging

http://i.minus.com/ibsHfIOAy7lBCj.png

I want to write some stuff to VS's output window so I can see what's going on, but it just gets flooded with all this other *stuff*. Is there some way I can write to a different "channel"? It's got that dropdown there, which I see AnkhSVN has added itself too...can I add another one with only my stuff in there maybe?

Answer (score 4):

Use Trace for this. You will either have an App.config file or a Web.config file in the project that is running. In this file add a [trace listener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0ectfxd.aspx).

When you call trace, which is very similar to Debug, you can specify the level (Info, Warning, Debug, Error). Based on this level you can decide where and how that information is saved.

[How to Trace and Debug in Visual Studio](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815788)

Comment: Nope. It's a VSX extension. All I've got is `source.extension.vsixmanifest`.

Comment: Ah! I thought your question was too easy. As far as I know all running .NET code has a config file somewhere, perhaps you can hunt it down? Otherwise I would suggest something like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [nlog2](http://nlog-project.org/) - a 3rd party logger. We've had a lot of success with nlog2.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the "Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window" option:

[image: Redirect Ouput to Immediate]

Although it says **all**, it will only redirect `Debug.WriteLine`, etc.

Alternatively you can suppress the noisy messages from the output window itself:

[image]

Comment: What is the "Immediate Window"? Where would it redirect my debug messages to exactly?

Comment: It's another tool window like the output window.  Show it with "Debug -> Windows -> Immediate" or `Ctrl+Alt+I`.

Comment: Turning off *all* the general output settings decreased the amount of output considerably.....but I can't seem to get rid of this stuff http://i.imgur.com/sX75Y.png

Comment: Ah.. I think I've seen that window before but wasn't sure what it was for. Unfortunately: http://i.imgur.com/pOPxP.png

Comment: Those binding warnings are due to WPF.  You can either fix the underlying binding problem or set "WPF Trace Settings -> Data Binding -> Off" to suppress them as well.

Comment: That's what they looked like to me too, so I I did turn that off, but I'm still getting them. I'm using the `Visual C# > Extensibility > Editor Classifier` template. I've barely touched it and all these errors keep coming up. Don't think I can fix them.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a visual studio addin (in default) you will have a connect.cs with a public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)

You can use this application object to do what you want to do.

```
DTE2 app = (DTE2)application;
OutputWindowPane XXX = app.ToolWindows.OutputWindow.OutputWindowPanes.Add("XXX");
```

Now you can use :

```
XXX.OutputString("some text" + Environment.NewLine);
```

And this text will appear in the "channel" called "XXX"